# How do I save flash videos from Safari?

Tags: safari, data-transfer

A long time ago, I found [this post](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080311022147414) online with some tips for finding files in the browser cache.  Specifically, Flash videos.  However, I'm currently running OS X 10.7.2 and Safari 5.1.2 and this method doesn't appear to be accurate anymore.

I also tried the RealPlayer Downloader method mentioned in the comments on that link, but it's not detecting the videos in the browser.

Can anybody think of an updated version of this?  Where might I find Safari's cache items to copy them?

Answer (score 3):

This is how you do it: [Capturing streaming video in OSX Lion](http://www.cultofmac.com/115523/capturing-streaming-video-in-os-x-lion-video-how-to/).
It's basically the same method as in the post you referred to, with the difference being that you access the file through the activity window in Safari instead of navigating to the temp file in Finder.

Comment: This works great on most sites, but doesn't seem to always work.  I don't know what king of streaming protocol breaks it, but one example site where it doesn't work would be http://www.info.com.

Comment: info.com isn't exactly a good example since it doesn't have video's of its own but shows video's of other sites like youtube, dailymotion and the likes. The youtube ones work just fine; dailymotion video's don't work. I get your point though. Unfortunately I don't know of an other way to capture streaming video's. Maybe someone else knows of an app or plugin that might achieve what you want. You could give a shot at Wheat Williams' recommendation.

Comment: My mistake, I meant to enter infoq.com.  iPad auto-correct broke it.

Comment: No problem. :) I hope you find a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend launching [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) and using the [DownThemAll!](http://www.downthemall.net/) plugin when you want to download a Flash video. It works so well for me that I've never tried to find an equivalent solution in Safari.

Comment: This plugin seems to be finding image files easily enough, but I don't see any way to get Flash videos through it.  I load the page, open the DTA console, select the "Pictures and Media" tab and see only image files.

Comment: @David I use the Firefox extension [Download YouTube Videos as MP4 and FLV](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/download-youtube/) which has a nice interface and works quite reliable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running 10.7.3 and I was trying to find this for a while. I ran into the Flash temp folder accidentally while looking for something else. For me, it was located in `/private/var/folders/` This worked in 10.7.2 as well.

In the Finder menu, if you click on **Go → Go to Folder → `/private/var/folders/`** and have a dig around, it will hopefully be there.

On my MacBook, it was a folder called

```
/private/var/folders/gd/xx16s42d6b1ffmyph3qy386r0000gn/T
```

The files themselves are called `FlashTemp.xxxx` (where `xxxx` is a random bunch of letters). I rename them to `Whatever.flv` and use MPlayerX to play them back.

I usually check this folder while the video is still open (and fully loaded) in Safari.

I've made an alias to this Flash temp folder in my downloads folder and use that if and when I need it.

Comment: I have `/private/var/folders/` and it contains some stuff, but it never seems to contain anything called `Flash*` anywhere in that hierarchy.

Comment: Hmmm... I usually check this folder while the video is still open (and fully loaded) in Safari. Is it the same case with you? I forgot to mention that.

I apologise for not formatting the post properly initially too. I'm new to SE!

Comment: I check it while the video is loading, yes.  (It's worth noting that this is similar to how I used to do it in Leopard, though I think the folder was somewhere else.)  Further testing seems to indicate that this method works fine for videos which are also available by using the Activity window in Safari.  But it's not working for me on videos like this one, for example: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/The-Code-is-the-Design

Comment: Yeah, I just tried that one and it didn't work for me either. So I guess they have to be available in the Activity window too...